# How to get k8s master ip address?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I have learn that I need to create a service so the deployment pods's ports will be exposed in the cluster. so the service provides me the port, and all is left is to find the cluster ip.

#### Problem

using https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript, I have created a deployment and a service.

#### Question

I'm not sure how to get the master address.

In bash, I would do:

```
> kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://<this-is-what-I-need>:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://<this-is-what-I-need>:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

but I'm not sure how to extract the ip. is there a better bash command? or any api for that? (maybe in https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript)?

---

#### more context

I created a demployment on my local machine for a docker image that exposes a service on port `4873`.

```
> kubectl get service stav-service1
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
stav-service1   NodePort   10.104.10.251   <none>        4873:30219/TCP   39m

> kubectl get deployment stav-deployment1
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
stav-deployment1   1/1     1            1           41m
```

I can reach that service from my local machine by running `curl http://192.168.64.2:30219`

Comment: is this Minikube?

Comment: yes. im using minikube

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
kubectl get nodes --selector=node-role.kubernetes.io/master -o jsonpath='{$.items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address}'
```

Comment: is this  what everyone do to access the cluster?

Comment: it doesn't work for DO kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using minikube as you stated in your comment please try the following one:

```
minikube ip
```